# python parent class information do not display

Tags: python

```
import sqlite3
sqlite3.Cursor.__base__
## output:   <class 'object'>
```

however, clearly, it inherited from Iterator, can see from the source code

```
class Cursor(Iterator[Any]):
```

and

```
issubclass(sqlite3.Cursor, Iterator) # previous edit was saying iterable, sorry
## output:   True
```

so, why does Python not properly display the parent class info? how to retrieve it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cursor object is [defined in C](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/699cb20ae6fdef8b0f13d633cf4858465ef3469f/Modules/_sqlite/cursor.h#L33) as far as I can tell, so it doesn't have a parent class.

As to why `issubclass` returns that, `issubclass` does [essentially a "duck typing check"](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/699cb20ae6fdef8b0f13d633cf4858465ef3469f/Lib/_collections_abc.py#L291) in some cases, as hinted at in the [ABC docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#id18):

> Checking isinstance(obj, Iterable) detects classes that are registered as Iterable or that have an `__iter__()` method. . .

It's talking about `isinstance` there, but `issubclass` works the same. You can see this with a simple test:

```
import typing

class T:  # Not an explicit subclass of "Iterable"
    def __iter__(self):
        pass

print(issubclass(T, Iterable))  # True
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing is the `.pyi` file aka [stub file](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubs.html#stub-files). It only contains the signature of the classes and methods along with type hints. You won't see the actual code inside those files.

These files are used by static type checkers only. In this case it inherits from a generic type so that type checkers know it's an `Iterator`.

From [PEP484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#user-defined-generic-types):

> You can include a Generic base class to define a user-defined class as
> generic.